# express - mongoose-auth routing issue

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express

I have the following coffescript code. Playing with express and [mongoose-auth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth), according to the [documentation](https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth#readme), using the middleware should enable the drop in routing. Which means that after I call /auth/twitter I should login with twitter. Unfortunately for some reason I got 404 error. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

```
express       = require 'express'
mongoose      = require 'mongoose'
mongoose_auth = require 'mongoose-auth'

UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema {}
User

UserSchema.plugin mongoose_auth, {
  everymodule: {
    everyauth: {
      User: () ->
        return User
    }
  }
  twitter: {
    everyauth: {
      myHostname:     'http://localhost:3000'
      consumerKey:    ''
      consumerSecret: ''
      redirectPath:   '/'
    }
  }
}

mongoose.model 'User', UserSchema

mongoose.connect 'mongodb://localhost/foobar'

User = mongoose.model 'User'

app = module.exports = express.createServer()

app.configure ->
  app.set 'views', "#{__dirname}/views"
  app.set 'view engine', 'jade'
  app.use require('stylus').middleware { src: "#{__dirname}/public" }
  app.use express.static "#{__dirname}/public"
  app.use express.bodyParser()
  app.use express.methodOverride()
  #app.use app.router
  app.use express.cookieParser()
  app.use express.session { secret: 'foobarmoocowetc' }
  mongoose_auth.middleware()

app.configure 'development', () ->
  app.use express.errorHandler {
    dumpExceptions: true
    showStack: true
  }

app.configure 'production', () ->
  app.use express.errorHandler()

app.get '/', (req, res) ->
  res.render 'page/index'

mongoose_auth.helpExpress app

app.listen 3000
console.log 'Express server listening on port %d in %s mode', app.address().port, app.settings.env
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't putting mongoose_auth.middleware() into express's middleware list.  You need

app.use mongoose_auth.midleware()

They way you have it the middleware is just created and ignored.  Probably you followed the example in the README but he's setting up his middleware when he calls `createServer` and you are using `app.use`, which is fine, but you need to pass the middleware function to `app.use` in order to properly register it.

That's **one** problem at least.  Fix that and see what happens.  There are a lot of configuration details that must be perfect to get everyauth working, so you may have a few other tweaks required as well.